# Accessing 2-dimensional array from an object class.

Tags: java, arrays, class

In Java I have a 2-dimensional array of objects but I can't access any of those array of objects in the object's class methods. What should I do?
Here's my class:

```
class GoPiece
{
    final int boardSize = 19;
    final int empty = 0;
    final int black = 1;
    final int white = 2;
    int pieceType = empty;
    int leftRight;
    int downUp;
    int turnPlayed;
    boolean legal;
    // GoPiece's Constructor with 3 parameters.
    GoPiece(int blackOrWhite, int horizontalCoordinate, int verticalCoordinate)
    {
        pieceType = blackOrWhite;
        leftRight = horizontalCoordinate;
        downUp = verticalCoordinate;
        if ((true));
    }
    // GoPiece's Constructor with 2 parameters.
    GoPiece(int horizontalCoordinate, int verticalCoordinate)
    {
        pieceType = empty;
        leftRight = horizontalCoordinate;
        downUp = verticalCoordinate;
    }
    // GoPiece's Constructor with no parameters.
    GoPiece()
    {
        leftRight = 0;
        downUp = 0;
    }
    // Initialize an empty Go board full of GoPieces.
    GoPiece[][] InitializeBoard()
    {        
        GoPiece[][] intersection = new GoPiece[boardSize][boardSize];
        for(int horizontal = 0; horizontal < boardSize; horizontal++)
        {
            for(int vertical = 0; vertical < boardSize; vertical++)
            {
                intersection[horizontal][vertical] = new GoPiece(horizontal,vertical);
            }
        }
        return intersection;
    }

    // Make a piece a certain type: empty, black, or white.
    public void SetType(int newType)
    {
        pieceType = newType;
    }

    public int GetType()
    {
        return pieceType;
    }

    public void CheckKill()
    {
        int foobar = this.GetType();
    }
}
```

I can then use InitializeBoard() in another part of my program to create a two dimensional array of GoPieces... this works, but How do I access all of those pieces other than the one I'm referencing in the class GoPiece's member functions?  I tried passing the whole array into one of GoPieces functions, but that didn't seem to work.

Go is an Ancient Chinese Board game.  The CheckKill() method above is where I tried to access different parts of the array, but failed.  Here I have some working dummy code.

Thank you.

Comment: please follow [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) and use initial lower case method names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a separate class to represent the board itself (including the current placement of pieces). The logic for creating a board, testing for a kill, etc., belong to the board, not to an individual piece.

Comment: In a phrase: smart board; dumb pieces.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  That's what I was thinking, but I'm trying to find a good way to do this.  I think it would be easier if my board size was set, but I want it to be changeable.  I'll keep trying to create a board class.

Comment: @EricMartin - You can create a board class that accepts a board size in the constructor. You can also write it in a way that allows the board to be resized dynamically. (You'd have to figure out a policy for dealing with any existing black or white pieces.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to call a method with the array like `InitializeBoard.GetType();` Where InitializeBoard is a 2 Dimensional Array?

You can't do that. You Must Specify which GoPiece to get out of InitializeBoard. Example: `InitializeBoard[0][0].GetType();` If you must call all methods, you can use a for loop to call each individually.